# Check printable for Unicode

Tags: python, unicode

I know that to check whether a string is printable, we can do something like:

```
def isprintable(s,codec='utf8'):
    try: 
        s.codec(codec)
    except UnicodeDecodeError: 
        return False
    else: 
        return True
```

But is there a way to do it with Unicode, not a string?
Btw, I'm working with tweets, and I convert the tweets to Unicode as follows

```
text=unicode(status.text)
```

Comment: There is no `.codec` method on strings.. did you mean `decode` perhaps?

Comment: The inverse is to `.encode` the text to UTF8. But all Unicode code points are encodable to UTF-8, so that will always succeed, so you need to clarify what 'printable' *means*.

Comment: Last but not least, if you load tweets via the JSON API, then they are already returned as `unicode` objects (provided you or the library you use use the `json` module to decode to python).

Comment: @MartijnPieters By 'printable,' I mean alphanumeric plus all the special letters on typical keyboard :)

Comment: You mean on a US keyboard; in various countries *outside* of the english-speaking world, 'typical keyboards' will be alien to you, I suspect. I'm afraid you are going to have to narrow that down a little.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry. Yes, I meant US Keyboard.

Comment: So, is Latin-1 acceptable? å, ø, ç, etc?

Comment: @MartijnPieters No. Basically, I'm trying to filter English tweets only, but since tweepy cannot filter by language, I'm building a workaround :(

Comment: I've seen plenty of English-language tweets with latin characters in it. And what about the all-popular Unicode emoticons? If you ignore those that'd make me go all（╯°□°）╯︵(\ .o.)\

Comment: @MartijnPieters You're right... but for now I guess I'll have to exclude those :(

Comment: might this be a problem with your terminal/console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a test for a range of codepoints, so you need a regular expression:

```
import re
# match characters from ¿ to the end of the JSON-encodable range
exclude = re.compile(ur'[\u00bf-\uffff]')

def isprintable(s):
    return not bool(exclude.search(s))
```

This will return `False` for any unicode text that has codepoints past `\u00BE` ("¾").

```
>>> isprintable(u'Hello World!')
True
>>> isprintable(u'Jeg \u00f8ve mit Norsk.')
False
```

Comment: What about characters past U+FFFF?

Comment: @ecatmur: JSON doesn't allow for those; tweepy uses the twitter JSON API. I suspect Twitter doesn't even accept those codepoints.

Comment: Well JSON does accept > 0xFFFF literally. Even with unicode escape sequences it's just surrogates e.g. `` = `"\ud840\udc00"`

Comment: @Esailija: right, because the ECMA-script standard specifies that source code is supposed to be encoded in UTF-16; codepoints over `\uffff` need to use surrogates. The JSON standard is a little ambiguous on that point, is allows for 'any Unicode character` as wel as four-hex-digit escape codes. The ECMA-script standard also has no escape sequence for codepoints over `\uFFFF`, btw, and the standard states that, unless stated otherwise, an implementation is presumed to only support the BMP codepoints.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have never seen languages that support \u not supporting this though

Comment: @Esailija: I know that narrow Unicode builds of Python < 3.3 do that, indeed, and you have given me some evidence that at least one JSON implementation does that, but the ECMA standard doesn't specify this explicitly, so I wouldn't count on it without some extensive testing. A tweet using characters outside of the BMP would be needed here to see what the Twitter API does for this case.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the JSON spec here says it on the final paragraph in `2.5 Strings` http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt. *To escape an extended character that is not in the Basic Multilingual
   Plane, the character is represented as a twelve-character sequence,
   encoding the UTF-16 surrogate pair.  So, for example, a string
   containing only the G clef character (U+1D11E) may be represented as
   "\uD834\uDD1E".* This is just about parsing, it doesn't matter if something is wide or narrow build.

Comment: Fantastic! I did not realise JSON had an RFC; I was looking at http://json.org instead.

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure a solution using codepoints is robust in the face of Unicode standard changes or different encodings.  A more abstract solution:

```
import unicodedata

if unicodedata.category(char) == 'Cc':
        raise UnhandledKeypressError('unprintable char')
```

In other words, a string is printable if all its chars (unicode objects) do not have property category having value 'control.'

For comparison, Qt's QChar.isPrint() :

> Returns true if the character is a printable character; otherwise returns false. This is any character not of category Cc or Cn.  Note that this gives no indication of whether the character is available in a particular font.