# Is it possible to get number of printable characters in string?

Tags: python, string-length, ansi-escape

Is it possible to get width of a string as it appears on the terminal?

Assuming the terminal supports ansi-escpace sequences, this

```
s = u"\u001b[31m" +"foo" + u"\u001b[0m"
print(len(s))
print(s)
```

will print

```
12
foo
```

with the second line in red. Given only the already concatenated `s`, is there an easy way to get the width of it (`3` in this case)?

Also `\t` is counted as `1` character, but thats easier to account for.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22632060/1692260. or `string.printable` if ASCII only.

Comment: It seems like you're effectively asking how to strip the ansi-escape sequences from a string, which has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14693701/984421.

Comment: @ekhumoro thanks that looks very promising. Unfortunately I have to leave it for now.

Comment: [_Printed length of a string in python_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14889454/674039), which didn't have any particularly promising answers either..

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I put together using the links in the comments,

```py
from re import compile

def line_width(s, tab_width=4):
    if '\n' in s:
        raise ValueError('String contains mutliple lines.')
    # https://stackoverflow.com/q/14693701/12035739
    ansi_be_gone = compile(r'(?:\x1B[@-_]|[\x80-\x9F])[0-?]*[ -/]*[@-~]')
    s = ansi_be_gone.sub('', s)
    return len(s) + s.count('\t') * (tab_width - 1)
```

Now,

```py
s = u"\u001b[31m" +"foo" + u"\u001b[0m"
print(len(s))
print(s)
```

Prints 3 to the console.